# R function creates a new data.frame within my data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Using `df` `data.frame`

```
set.seed(123) 
date <- as.Date(seq(as.Date("2003-01-01"), as.Date("2008-05-31"), by = 1), format="%Y-%m-%d") 
flow   <- runif(1978, 48530, 1250365) 
df   <- data.frame(date, flow)
```

and `EcoHydRology` package, I separated `baseflow` `bf` from `flow` using `BaseflowSeparation` function.

```
library(EcoHydRology)
df$bf <- BaseflowSeparation(df$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3)
```

The function creates two new columns `bf.bt` and `bf.qft`

I wanted to plot the three parameters `flow`, `bf.bt` and `bf.qft` on one graph using `geom_line` so I tried converting the data.frame from wide to long format using `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df <- tidyr::gather(df, "parameter", "value", 2:4)
```

I got this error

`Error: Position must be between 0 and n`

I checked `df` to find out that `BaseflowSeparation` function created new `data.frame` `bf` of two columns within `df`

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1978 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date: Date, format: "2003-01-01" "2003-01-02" "2003-01-03" ...
 $ flow: num  394151 995943 540053 1109771 1178816 ...
 $ bf  :'data.frame':   1978 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ bt : num  168374 171233 172381 150429 120018 ...
  ..$ qft: num  178506 824710 367671 959342 1058798 ...
```

Any suggestion how to get the output of `BaseflowSeparation` function as two columns not a new `data.frame`?

Comment: Use df <- cbind(df, BaseflowSeparation(df$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3))

Comment: @chinsoon12
Many thanks. Can you please write it as an answer?

Comment: @chinsoon12
If I have many sites and I'm using dpyr to group based on the site. Any suggestions how to use this function within dplyr? Many thanks again

Comment: Does each site has a df? Or is there a column called site in the df?

Comment: It's a column called site in the df.

Comment: Something like df %>% group_by(site) %>% mutate(BaseflowSeparation(flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3) %>% ungroup()

Comment: If mutate doesn't work use do(cbind(., BaseflowSeparation(.$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3)))

Comment: @chinsoon12 Many thanks. Mutate didn't work but do(cbind.) worked fine. I really appreciate your time and help. It would be great if you add you comment as answer to accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dplyr group_by to perform calculation by site, then use do to cbind results from BaseflowSeparation with original data.frame for each group then ungroup to rbind groups

```
df %>% 
    group_by(site) %>% 
    do(cbind(., BaseflowSeparation(.$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3))) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help

Comment: No problem! Cheers