# Shiny: dplyr returns error messages

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

Using `diamonds` dataset and the code below

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)

  diam <- diamonds %>%
    dplyr::select(cut, color, carat, price) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(cut, color) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(cut, color)

  diam[c(10:30, 100:140, 300:500, 765:963,1476:1987,2469:3786,5000:6000,
             8654:9876, 11000:12670, 21678:23456,35648:37896,
             45469:46789,49876:51346), c(3, 4)]  <- NA 

  write.csv(diam, "diam.csv")
```

I created `diam.csv` file to be used in the shiny app below

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        tags$h1(tags$strong("Shiny app")),
        fileInput("file", "Upload your file"), 
        width =2),
      mainPanel(width =10,
                uiOutput("tb")))))

#server

server <- function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.csv(file1$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',')
  })
  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}

    df_summary <- data()

    df_summary1 <- df_summary %>%
      dplyr::select(cut, color, carat, price)
    summary(df_summary1)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  }) 

  output$stats <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}

    diam1 <- data()
    print(
      diam_stats <- diam1 %>%
        dplyr::select(cut, color, carat) %>%
        dplyr::arrange(cut, color) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(cut, color) %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(carat)) %>%
        dplyr::summarise_each(funs(
          mean(., na.rm=T), 
          sd(., na.rm=T),
          n()))
    )
  }) 

  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5()             
    else
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                  tabPanel(h3("Summary", align="center"), 
                           tableOutput("sum")), 
                  tabPanel(h3("Data"), 
                           dataTableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel(h3("Stats"), 
                           dataTableOutput("stats")))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I got this error in the summary tab

> no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('standardGeneric', 'genericFunction', 'function', 'OptionalFunction', 'PossibleMethod', 'optionalMethod')"

and this error in the stats tab

> argument "funs" is missing, with no default

I'm using `dplyr_0.4.3`

Any suggestions how to fix these errors?

**Update**

Below is a print screen of the errors

[image]

And here what appears in the console

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3606
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('standardGeneric', 'genericFunction', 'function', 'OptionalFunction', 'PossibleMethod', 'optionalMethod')"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    73: select_
    72: dplyr::select
    71: ..redirect
    70: %>%
    69: renderTable [C:\R\Shiny\diam_app/app.R#28]
    68: func
    67: output$sum
     1: runApp
Warning: Error in lazyeval::as.lazy_dots: argument "funs" is missing, with no default
Stack trace (innermost first):
    83: lazyeval::as.lazy_dots
    82: funs_
    81: inherits
    80: is.fun_list
    79: stopifnot
    78: colwise_
    77: summarise_each_
    76: dplyr::summarise_each
    75: ..redirect
    74: %>%
    73: print
    72: exprFunc [C:\R\Shiny\diam_app/app.R#42]
    71: widgetFunc
    70: func
    69: renderFunc
    68: output$stats
     1: runApp
```

Here is the `sessioninfo()`

```
    R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lazyeval_0.1.10     EcoHydRology_0.4.12 DEoptim_2.2-3       topmodel_0.7.2-2    operators_0.1-8     plotly_3.4.13       googleVis_0.5.10   
 [8] tidyr_0.4.1         raster_2.5-2        leaflet_1.0.1       chron_2.3-47        date_1.2-34         scales_0.4.0        dplyr_0.4.3        
[15] DT_0.1              ggplot2_2.1.0       pixmap_0.4-11       RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7 sp_1.2-3            XML_3.98-1.4        shiny_0.13.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] reshape2_1.4.1   lattice_0.20-33  colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3.5  yaml_2.1.13      base64enc_0.1-3  withr_1.0.1      DBI_0.3.1       
 [9] plyr_1.8.3       stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.3    gtable_0.2.0     htmlwidgets_0.6  devtools_1.11.1  memoise_1.0.0    labeling_0.3    
[17] httpuv_1.3.3     curl_0.9.7       parallel_3.2.5   Rcpp_0.12.4      xtable_1.8-2     jsonlite_0.9.19  mime_0.4         gridExtra_2.2.1 
[25] png_0.1-7        digest_0.6.9     stringi_1.0-1    RJSONIO_1.3-0    grid_3.2.5       tools_3.2.5      magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.1  
[33] httr_1.1.0       viridis_0.3.4    R6_2.1.2         git2r_0.14.0
```

**Update** May_04

I didn't realize that `EcoHydRology_0.4.12` package was the source of this error message. That's why it was not included in the example above.

Thanks to @**enpitsu** who pointed out the source of the problem and his nice solution through loading `EcoHydRology` package first then `dplyr`

Below is an example to reproduce the same error including `EcoHydRology_0.4.12`.
The example will work fine if you load the packages in this order

```
library(EcoHydRology) 
library(dplyr)
```

However, if you switch the order, it will return error messages

```
set.seed(123) 
date <-  rep (as.Date(seq(as.Date("2003-01-01"), as.Date("2008-05-31"), by = 1), format="%Y-%m-%d"), 2)
siteID <- c(rep("site1", 1978), rep("site2", 1978))
flow   <- runif(3956, 48530, 1250365) 
df   <- data.frame(date, siteID, flow)

library(dplyr)
library(EcoHydRology)

df1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(siteID, flow) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(siteID) %>% 
  dplyr::do(cbind(., BaseflowSeparation(.$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3))) 

summary(df1)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(siteID, flow, bt, qft) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(siteID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_each(funs(
    mean(., na.rm=T), 
    sd(., na.rm=T),
    n()))

df2
```

Comment: I just ran your code and I didn't get an error on the summary tab. On the stats tab I got an error due to a typo. To fix the typo, in the output$stats <- renderDataTable method change diam_stats <- data() to diam1 <- data()

Comment: @AllanT
Thanks for your time and help. I run the code after fixing the typo and I'm still getting the same error messages

Comment: Maybe update all your packages? R 3.2.5?

Comment: @AllanT 
According to my latest version of Rstudio, all packages are up to date.

Comment: Can you try restarting R and then running it again? Make sure you have no packages loaded other than dplyr, shiny, and ggplot2.

Comment: @Shorpy
Many thanks. It is working fine now :-) However, my final app has many other packages than only "dplyr, shiny and ggplot2. When I try it using all other packages, it keeps returning the same errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shorpy
With all the packages above (in the question) loaded, using dplyr in Rstudio (not even shiny app) keeps returning errors. For example
  diam1 <- read.csv("diam.csv")    
  diam_stats <- diam1 %>%
    dplyr::select(cut, color, carat) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(cut, color) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(cut, color) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(carat)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_each(funs(
      mean(., na.rm=T), 
      sd(., na.rm=T),
      n()))
  diam_stats
returned this error
Error in lazyeval::as.lazy_dots(dots) : 
  argument "funs" is missing, with no default

Comment: try adding packages one at a time and re-running the code each time, until it breaks ...

Comment: @BenBolker
Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have now been able to reproduce this error.  The package causing the problem is:
`EcoHydRology_0.4.12`

Unfortunately, detaching this packages with `detach("package:EcoHydRology", unload=TRUE)` did not get rid of the error.  Restarting my R session did fix the problem until I loaded the `EcoHydRology` package again.  One solution is to run this without that package loaded.

---

UPDATE: I believe I have solved the problem now.

When I ran `library(EcoHydRology)` and looked carefully at the console messages I noticed that it printed:

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    %>%
```

That is not good and not easy to load by `dplyr::%>%` (which does not work).

However, if we run `library(EcoHydRology)` and then run `library(dplyr)` again after it, the `dplyr` package will mask `%>%` from other packages and switch back to its version.  Now run the code and we don't get the error.

---

Originally suggested changing `funs()` to `dplyr::funs()`, but that did not solve the problem. (edited to remove extraneous text)

Comment: you mean `dplyr::funs()` in the second code chunk, right?

Comment: @enpitsu

Thanks for your time and help. However, it didn't work.

Comment: Corrected to `dplyr`, yes, that is what I meant.  Too bad it didn't work.

Comment: finding the package responsible is an important clue. (It might be worth deleting the first half of your answer, for clarity.)

Comment: you *definitely* deserve the bounty! (does making sure to load `EcoHydRology` first and *then* `dplyr` solve the problem?)

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is coming from the operators package (because EcoHydRology is importing the `%>%` from the operators package (quickly write an object to file). It might be worth emailing them about this because the forward pipe is common enough that they should maybe refactor to not rely on this function (which should probably be deprecated).

Comment: @Shorpy it's ok for them to import it - but they are clearly exporting it as well (or more likely simply depending on the operators package), which is causing the problem

Comment: @hadley Yeah, this is what their NAMESPACE file looks like: `# Export all names
exportPattern(".")

# Import all packages listed as Imports or Depends
import(
  operators,
  topmodel,
  DEoptim,
  XML
)` So it looks like everything is exported.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, we need to check to see if `package:EcoHydRology` is loaded, detach `package:dplyr` first, then detach `package:EcoHydRology`, to enable the reload the `package:dplyr`...

The solution is to use `require()`, to check if `package:EcoHydRology`is loaded. The advantage of `require()` over `library()` is that it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, enabling us to use it to evaluate the result of its operation.

Thus, if the `package:EcoHydRology` is already loaded (TRUE), we can specify the detach order in the `if` construct, to unload the packages in the correct order `dplyr`, then `EcoHydRology`.

We are now able to load the required `package:dplyr` without issue.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(dplyr)
library(EcoHydRology)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
if ( require(EcoHydRology) ) {
  detach("package:dplyr", unload = TRUE)
  detach("package:EcoHydRology", unload = TRUE)
  require(dplyr)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        tags$h1(tags$strong("Shiny app")),
        fileInput("file", "Upload your file"),
        width =2),
      mainPanel(width =10,
        uiOutput("tb")))))

#server

server <- function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.csv(file1$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',')
  })
  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}

    df_summary <- data()

    df_summary1 <- df_summary %>%
      dplyr::select(cut, color, carat, price)
    summary(df_summary1)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })

  output$stats <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}

    diam1 <- data()
    print(
      diam_stats <- diam1 %>%
        dplyr::select(cut, color, carat) %>%
        dplyr::arrange(cut, color) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(cut, color) %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(carat)) %>%
        dplyr::summarise_each(funs(
          mean(., na.rm=T),
          sd(., na.rm=T),
          n()))
    )
  })

  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5()
    else
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",
        tabPanel(h3("Summary", align="center"),
          tableOutput("sum")),
        tabPanel(h3("Data"),
          dataTableOutput("table")),
        tabPanel(h3("Stats"),
          dataTableOutput("stats")))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. It worked fine with this reproducible example now. However, I forgot to add to the question above that in one tab of my shiny app I'm using the two packages dplyr and EcoHydrRology at the same time as in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807155/r-function-creates-a-new-data-frame-within-my-data-frame 
df %>% 
    group_by(site) %>% 
    do(cbind(., BaseflowSeparation(.$flow, filter_parameter = 0.925, passes = 3))) %>% 
    ungroup()

Your solution fixed all errors in all tabs except the tab in which I use both packages together

Comment: My recommendation would be to create an interim result. For example, you can create EcoHydrRology result and then unload EcoHydrRology and then insert the interim result into a dplyr pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Deatching and attaching the packages does affect the tab in which I use EcoHydRology. So it will now work fine only for this tab or it will work fine all other tabs that use dplyr but the EcoHydRology tab won't work. However, loading EcoHydRology first and then dplyr does solve the problem.

Comment: Please, check the update in the question. I have posted the code.